Doctor enters the minds of coma patients
I am trying to find the title of a movie about coma recovery. A scientist notices that the EEG/brainwaves of several coma patients are starting to sync.
He is able to enter their mind by going into a near death state.  He finds that each have created a fantasy world.  The fantasy worlds begin to deteriorate and the scientist leads them to an exit.  Once they go through the exit, they wake from their coma.

Time frame for when you saw this movie? How old was the movie when you saw it (TV/Cable/DVD released)? Any notable actors? Any help is appreciated.

I am looking for this movie too, does anyone know the title? (I am actually looking for the book it is based on)
The movie tells the story of a couple who seeks the help of said scientists after their daughter falls into a coma as a result of a car accident. With the scientist's help, the little girl's brother syncs his mind to her sister's in order to guide her out of the coma. Any help would be appreciated :)

I think it's an episode of The Outer Limits titled The Other Side, (1999).

The brain waves of two comatose patients, Adam (Aaron Smolinski) and
  Lisa (Emmanuelle Vaugier), fall into sync while they're hooked up to
  the NISA and one of them whispers the other's name. 
...
What Neal doesn't know is that Adam and Lisa have landed in an idyllic
  parallel consciousness and are falling in love.
...
Desperate to try the technique on other comatose subjects, Neal loses
  patience and makes the journey himself.

The ending matches your description as well.  The full episode is available on Hulu.

Is it  psychological thriller film The Cell. Most of the plot-line doesn't matches but it follows as 

Child psychologist Catherine Deane (Jennifer Lopez) is an expert in an
  experimental treatment for coma patients: a virtual reality device
  that allows her to enter into the minds of her patients and attempt to
  coax them into consciousness.When serial killer Carl Rudolph Stargher (Vincent D'Onofrio) falls into a coma before the FBI can locate his final victim, Agent Novak (Vince Vaughn) persuades Deane to enter Stargher's mind and discover the victim's location.


It's superficially similar to The Cell (dream sharing, coma), but the particulars don't match...
